# How come it always says \tikzlibrary{calc} is missing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Whenever I put 2 trees onto a document, the system always tells me I am missing `\tikzlibrary{calc}` on the second tree (I have the same line for both trees) on this line
`\draw[dashed,rounded corners=10]($(1-1) + (-.2,.25)$)rectangle($(2-2) +(.2,-.25)$);` even though I have it right above it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)
Please always supply a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) when asking.

Comment: Why did you name a node `$(1-1) + (-.2,.25)$`? Does replacing it with A fix the problems?

Comment: The correct syntax is `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`. Put this in the *preamble* (before `\begin{document}`) and after loading TikZ with `\usepackage{tikz}` and not (never) inside the TikZ picture! Now it should work. If not, please provide a MWE as asked.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you so much that was my problem! Sorry for the confusion I will always post MWE in the future.

Comment: @masu `$(1-1) + (-.2,.25)$` is not a name. It is a calculation of coordinate. Hence the need for the `calc` library of TikZ.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I found out eventually. There was no MWE in the question and I constructed mine a wrong way (the compiler error was the one I was referring to).